# Query a list of field values of a node in drupal 7

Tags: nodes, entities, database, log-messages

I am new to drupal 7, I have a question and hope to receive your helpful responses! :D

I've created a new content type named 'school', and create a custom 'city' field in it.
After that, I create two new nodes of 'school', and their city are 'London' and 'Beijing'.
How can I get a list of city of schools programmatically in Drupal 7?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module, it comes with all sorts of reporting features. And all sorts of hooks if you want to use them in your own custom modules.

Here is an excerpt from its [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363):

> Forena Reports is built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports.
>
> It is designed to leverage existing knowledge of HTML, CSS, SQL and JavaScript to help you create rich interactive web reports.

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena),
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).